# Troubleshooting periodic noise in raw data collected from ADC

Tags: adc, noise, digital-communications

We are working on an ADC that has maximum sampling rate of 2.5MSps at clock frequency of 40MHz and Vref of 2.5V. The architecture is SAR and it carries out the calibration internally. 
Currently we are running at clock frequency of 32MHz and sampling rate of 1.25MSps.
We are reconstructing the analog waveform using MATLAB from the raw data collected and are observing a periodic noise. We are unable to comprehend the cause of this noise.
[image]
The noise is approximately equal in amplitude ~80mV. We have also observed noise on power supply of the FPGA that is collecting the raw data but the frequency of the noise was very low. 
We need your help in troubleshooting this noise. Even if you could give us any pointers to look at, that would be greatly appreciated. Please let us know if you need further information regarding the setup of the system.
EDIT: Schematic is attached below. Analog input is given to the "Input circuit". C42 is shown DNP but we have connected a capacitor of 1uF 16V. We are using Analog Discovery 2 as our signal source. 
Regards.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's correlated noise, if you have to use "noise" as part of the description. You should study the details you see to help track it down. I already see: (1) on the rising slope you see an *up* followed quickly by a *down* but on the falling slope you see the opposite; (2) at the trough and peak the spacing is wider, but on the rising and falling slopes where the derivative magnitude is larger the spacing is narrower. So this correlated noise isn't just an isolated clock source, but it is also tied into the signal you show. I do think the ADC is implicated here.

Comment: The ups and downs @jonk noted could be the edges of a digital signal coupling into the ADC input. The ups could be positive edges. The downs negative. So, somewhere on the board there could be a digital signal that looks like that. Perhaps the first step would be to observe the ADC input with an oscilloscope and see if the edges are actually present at the ADC input. If they are, then you can try looking for a source. Looks like the frequency is between 30 and 40 kHz. Any HW signal (maybe a PWM signal) or SW process operating at that speed?

Comment: What does the analogue input to the ADC look like? Show your circuit and input chain.

Comment: What is the output impedance of the signal source? Are you sampling multiple input channels via analog signal multiplexing? Could this be be ghosting? (And as others have already stated, use an oscilloscope to observe the power supply rails to ensure they are clean (noise free), and use an oscilloscope to observe the applied sine wave signal to ensure it is clean.)

Comment: @mkeith I don't think you're right; such spikes would be a bit atypical, and also, they should be consistent on a time scale, not related to the slope  of the signal of interest.

Comment: What's the actual ADC type? This looks *a lot* like you've got problems with the SAR algorithm it runs. (I really think @jonk is on point with his ADC concerns here)

Comment: I am open to being wrong. HOWEVER, determining whether the spikes are on the input seems like a good first step.

Comment: If the ADC is a capacitive redistribution type (very common now), those spikes *could* be artifacts of a short current spike at the acquisition phase. As already noted, the *specific* ADC needs to be identified.

Comment: @mkeith near our input circuit we only have LDOs ADP1720 placed and no other digital circuit.
We can't check input signal at exact pin of the chip but we checked at the "input circuit" but couldn't find these edges on it.

Comment: @jonk We had used the same ADC in chip on board package and these edges did not appear on the raw data.

Comment: Look at the spikes numerically. If all of them end with a series of 1's of 0's that is an important clue. I have seen similar issues with SARs when the ground or power is noisy. See my answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441656/invensense-mpu9150-accelerometer-raw-values-even/441973#441973

Comment: Your disturbance appears to be phase coherent to the carrier tone. If you look at a few more cycles, you could confirm this. If so its likely a digital domain problem.

Comment: If it is not an actual physical signal on the input then looking at the ADC reference might be a good idea. If that looks OK, looking at the acquisition code. It does appear that the voltage separation between glitch events is uniform. Graph a few more cycles and draw horizontal lines.

Comment: When I zoom in on the graph, it appears that maybe only a single point is misplaced at each glitch location. If you look at the raw data (in a spreadsheet or whatever) is that how it looks? Maybe it is a data dependent bug in the code that is reconstructing the ADC data into a voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to read more than 1 byte in more than 1 read operation to read an ADC value?

If so, you need to synchronise reading correctly to ADC conversions.

If the ADC periodically samples between reading the MSB and the LSB, you will get periodic error that looks exactly like this.

For ADC samples 1.01 and 0.99, you can read 1, then .99, Put them together, guess what? 1.99.

I can't say this is exactly your problem because you don't tell us what the ADC is - resolution, interface typ, or link to the datasheet, and I can't enlarge those schematics in the middle of editing an answer. But it's one possible (likely) problem that has bitten someone here before.

Comment: Yes! The glitches are all the same size and they occur at regular voltage intervals.